# Kmeans algorithm in Spark,

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cluster-computing

Recently I am doing clustering in spark, I use Kmeans-clustering in spark to do some computing

I have a dataset, just like this:
- 1,2,3,4
- 2,3,4,5
- 1,2,4,5

now I want to cluster the first three column, and how could I get the prediction of the first three column as one column without loss the last column, just like

- 1,2,3,1,4
- 2,3,4,2,5
- 1,2,4,3,5

the forth column is the prediction column.

```
val kmeansData = model.transform(input)
```

the code above just use dataframe as a parameter to make prediction

Comment: the data is (1,2,3,4),(2,3,4,5),(1,2,4,5)，in three rows

Answer (score 0):

You can specify what column to use for prediction when you're creating instance of `kmeans`, like that:

```
val kmeans = new KMeans()
  .setK(3)
  .setFeaturesCol("features")
  .setPredictionCol("prediction")
val model = kmeans.fit(trainingData)
val kmeansData = model.transform(vectoredInput)
```

As clustering (and, I think, most of Spark ML algorithms) works with columns of type `Vector`, you have to first combine your three separate columns into one vector:

```
val cols = Array("1", "2", "3")
val assembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(cols).setOutputCol("features")
val vectoredInput = assembler.transform(input)
```

You can find more details here: https://medium.com/rahasak/k-means-clustering-with-apache-spark-cab44aef0a16